# Calculating Variance(Difference) of amounts between two years

Tags: powerbi

I am new to Power BI. I have to calculate the difference of amount of the year(say 2019 and 2018). Current year and Last year will be calculated automatically.I have to apply filter on the same column and retrieve the values respectively.
CY = YEAR(TODAY())
PY = CY - 1

I have tried calculating the difference using the measures:

```
Sum_of_PY = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( SAPCube[PL CY ITM - EUR] ),
        FILTER ( 
            SAPCube, 
            SAPCube[Fiscal Period.Year] = [PY]
        )
    )
```

and

```
Sum_of_CY = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( SAPCube[PL CY ITM - EUR] ), 
        FILTER ( 
            SAPCube, 
            SAPCube[Fiscal Period.Year] = [CY]
        )
    )
```

For, CY I'm getting the values but for PY,
I'm getting blank instead of the value.

Comment: What are measures `[PY]` and `[CY]` ? Please [edit] your post to include those measures too.

Comment: Kindly Provide the Same Data and the Expected Output.

Comment: Updated! Will attach the picture of the table too.. If needed

Comment: Are you trying to evaluate the measures within a context that filters `SAPCube[Fiscal Period]`?

Comment: Yes, Same column I'm filtering and trying to retrieve the data